# How can I call my rails mailer functionality from a different app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I recently created a rails app so that I could send emails using `ActionMailer` and **Gmail**, via `SMTP`. The app will send an email to the user when a new user is created. Everything was successful.

Now I was wondering how do I use this "Mailer App" as, perhaps, a web-service?
How would I go about calling my mailer app from a different application, thus eliminating the need to setup all of the ActionMailer code in additional applications but delivering email.

The other application could be as simple as signing up a new user with a name and email, like I did in the Mailer App.

Here is my code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save

      ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver

      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully     created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

**config/env/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
....
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :domain               => 'gmail.com',
 :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
 :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

# Raises error for missing translations
# config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**sample_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
 </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hi <%= @user.name %></h1>
   <p>
     Sample mail sent using smtp.
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**example.mailer.rb**

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: "t@@@@@@@gmail.com"

def sample_email(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably envisioning a microservices architecture. There are many resources on that, one example is [this blog post](https://www.toptal.com/ruby/how-to-set-up-a-microservices-architecture).

In short, when moving your functional components to isolated blocks you have to provide means for them to communicate with each other. There is endless variety of ways to accomplish that, most popular being HTTP APIs or use of dedicated message brokers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think for what I am trying to learn and accomplish it might be a little overkill though. I was looking for how to use something like `HTTParty` to perhaps call the Mailer App and deliver an email using the @name and @email variables of the new application.